# How std containers can store different types?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, std

I have structure like this

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    typedef T value_type;
};

// what i want
someContainer.push(A<int>());
someContainer.push(A<float>());
// ...
```

Is it possible to store `struct A` with different template arguments in some of std containers like vector? I understand, that one `std::vector` should store one type and `A` with template arg `int`, and `A` with template arg `double` is different type, but if template arguments doesn't change `sizeof` of type, why we can't store it in container?

Comment: You can't store objects of different types because they are of different types. Size is not the determining factor, type safety is.

Comment: @molbdnilo Well we have the obscurity of `std::vector<std::any>` (where imo any of use of it is very likely attempting to solve an XY problem).

Comment: there are many ways to store objects of different type in a container. Which one to choose depends. There is `std::variant`, `std::any` or you could make them inherit from a common base

Comment: As already mentioned, this question feels very much like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the actual and underlying problem you need to solve?

Comment: some context would help: Why do you want to store them in the same vector? How do you intend to use them?

Comment: Even if you can store the data, how you would handle it later. If you later access someContainer[9]... how to use it? Run time switch over data types? Well, can be done with `std::variant`. But it looks like a general design problem

Comment: you are basically asking for type erasure. With type erasure the easy part is to erase the type, the tricky part is to restore the type information when you need it. As `A<int>` and `A<float>` have nothing in common, what you get for free is just a vector of elements that you can do nothing with. In other words: You need to tell how you want to use elements of the vector and that determines how you can store them